# Sed change a tag and keep part of the contents

Tags: sed, command-line, scripting, text-formatting

I have a large text file with multiple occurrences of a tag containing a URL:

```
[tag]https://example.com/222389/link/11835457224168404[/tag]
```

I need to reformat the tags as follows:

```
[new-tag]11835457224168404[/new-tag]
```

(capture just the part of the url after 'link' (the 'id') and modify the tag to 'new-tag':

- There can be multiple tags per line;
- The tag locations are not uniform - they are found in random positions throughout the file;
- The tag content can have a space at the start (' http'), use 'http://" or 'https://' and sometimes use 'www';
- The tag occasionally has content or space at the end (after the 'id') such as follows:

  ```
  [tag]https://example.com/222389/link/11835457224168404/qwertyiop[/tag]
  ```

  or

  ```
  [tag]https://example.com/222389/link/11835457224168404?link=11835457224168401    [/tag]
  ```
- There are sometimes occurrences of '[tag]' on their own (without the closing [/tag] or 'http') that need to be ignored.

How can I do this with sed or alternatives?

Comment: Are "tags" always numbers? If not how can you tell the tag in https://example.com/222389/link/11835457224168404/qwertyiop is not the qwertyiop? If a "[tag]" is on its own is to be ignored can we assume that when it is not to be ignored the "[/tag]" is on the same line?

Comment: Desired format: [tag]id[/tag]. The id is always the group of digits after '/link/' e.g. 11835457224168404. '/link/' is a constant. Sometimes that id (the group of digits) is followed by text that needs to be removed e.g. '/qwertiop' or ?link=xyz.

Comment: ^^ Yes, the target is any occurrence of  opening tag followed by a closing tag - i.e. [tag]URL[/tag] but not a solo [tag] or [/tag]. There can be multiple tags on one line (e.g.  "lorem ipsum [tag]URL[/tag] dolor sit amet,  [tag]URL[/tag] consectetur adipiscing elit [tag]").

Comment: Are the tags _really_ in square brackets? If they were XML tags, you could use XML parsing tools like `xmlstarlet`. This would make thi processing of the data much more robust.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Strategy

Whilst it is possible to write regular expressions which **don't** match multi-character strings, they get complicated. We will use a trick to convert `[tag]` and `[/tag]` into single characters and then use negated character classes. In this script I will use control-a and control-b. It is **critical** that these characters don't appear in the file. As these are hard to type, I will use a couple of variables `s` and `e` for the start and end tags. I use `notend` to represent any sequence of characters which is not the end tag.

```
#!/bin/bash
s=$'\001' # control-a, for the start tag 
e=$'\002' # control-b, for the end tag
notend="[^$e]*" # expression for not the end tag.
# Program, Change the tags into single characters
# change matched pairs of tags into new form
# convert any unmatched tags back to original form
prog='
s:\[tag]:'"$s"':g
s:\[/tag]:'"$e"':g
s:'"$s$notend"'/link/\([0-9]*\)'"$notend$e"':[new-tag]\1[/newtag]:g
s:'"$s"':[tag]:g
s:'"$e"':[/tag]:g'

# run sed, passing any parameters  
sed -e "$prog" "$@"
```

### usage

Save this script, make it executable, then run it giving the datafile as a parameter and redirecting the output to a temp file. examine the temp file.